# Any name for a data structure like an array/list but with additional elements between the usual elements?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, collections

I sometimes find myself needing a one-dimensional collection of items of alternating "outer" and "inner" types. For example, for types `A` and `B`, the structure could hold a sequence of types:

`A`, `B`, `A`, `B`, `A`

where `A` and `B` are respectively the "outer" and "inner" types. (The sequence always starts and ends with the "outer" type.)

It's like an array/vector/list, but with additional members (of a different type) inserted "between" the array/vector/list's elements.

Such a structure is of course easy to implement using, for example, two arrays (of sizes n and n-1), or a special linked list using two types of nodes. But I feel a clean interface is warranted.

I have no idea what to call it. Is there any existing or sensible name for such a thing?

Comment: Can you provide an example of where this is useful?

Comment: @Welbog In my current use case `A`s are overlapping surfaces and `B`s are cutting planes where those surfaces are to be cut and spliced.